# What to do if the phone emulator starts when running in Android Studio the emulator process for avd has terminated?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-virtual-device

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujMyj.png)
that error

Launch emulators
**Pixel 4**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced that before, I don't remember well but probably try to start the emulator from the "devices" tab in Android Studio with a Cold Start, wait for it to finish startup and then run the application.

If it continue failing then I would restart Android Studio and if it still fails, ultimately delete and create a new emulator.

Answer (score 0):

My method was clear invalidate cache and also kill the adb process from the windows taskbar and restart the android studio again.